# AngularJS: when checking for object null, returning the wrong message

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am adding a couple of alerts for when a record gets updated based on the response of service call.

When I check if there is any data in the response:

```
if (response.data === null)
```

This part seems to not be respected and the alert for update on record succeeded gets shown, and if you look in the screen shot, the response.data is null.

I am not sure why the simple if is not working, or if I am looking at the response Object incorrectly.

Can someone please lend a hand so that I can understand the best practice on how to do this?

Thank you.

UPDATED IMAGE

[image]

Comment: you need `if (response.data === null)`. You are currently checking for a 'null' string.

Comment: hello jjenzz, please see my updated screen shot.

Comment: The code you've written is telling it to succeed when there *isn't any* data... It sounds like what you really want is `if (response.data !== null)`

Comment: yes you are correct. if no data, then go to the we're sorry alert.

Comment: You've updated the screenshot *again* but this time to `if (!response.data) {` when you need `if (response.data) {`. You've said in your OP "When I check if there **is** any **data** in the response:" but what you've said and what you've coded are two different things :P

Comment: if the response.data is null, then the code should go to the we're sorry alert, when there is data, then the congratulations alert.

Comment: you want to use `if (response.data)` not `if (!response.data)` You are sayig if there is no response show the congrats alert

Comment: @Ronnie thanks for reiterating what I keep trying to explain haha

Comment: haha ^ I didn't read the other comments...funny and common mistake by OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help explain why you're not getting the results you're expecting (read comments in code):

```
function boooooom(msg) {
    alert('We\'re sorry folks! ' + msg);
}

$http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: 'api/StorePage/PutStorePage?StorePageId=' + this.newpage.StorePageID,
    data: storePage,
})
    .then(
        // This callback will be called when the response is *available*
        function(response) {
            // Change this to `response.data` instead of `!response.data`
            if (response.data) {
                $scope.pages = response.data;
                alert('Congrats!');
            } else {
                boooooom('No data');
            }
        }, 

        // This callback is called if an error occurs or if the server 
        // returns a response with an *error* status.
        //
        // *Your* request hasn't caused an error as it *has* responded 
        // and the response is a 200 status (which is not an error status) 
        // so this callback doesn't get called.
        function(response) {
            boooooom('Houston we have a problem');
        }
    )
    // It looks like you always want to `clearFields` for both failure and success
    // so you can just do that here, which will do that for you.
    .finally(clearFields);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check using only:

```
if ( response.data )
```

This check if:

- null
- false
- undefined
- 0
- NaN
- empty ("")

Comment: Hi Lucas Costa, I tried your recommendation and updated the screen shot. Please if you have a chance, take a look.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why yours is not working, can you do the below and try.

```
if(response && response.data === null && typeof response.data === "object")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for the value `null`, not the string `"null`".

In your post you used `response.data === null`, but in the screenshot, you are doing `response.data === 'null'`. That is checking for a string value of `'null'`, not gonna happen! Edit the `if` statement in the screenshot to look like the one in your post ;)

The next thing to do is to wrap the entire block in curly braces.

Right now, your code is the equivalent of:

```
if (response.data === null) {
    $scope.pages = response.data;
}
alert("....");
clearFields();
```

Incase all the desired code in the block:

```
if (response.data === null) {
    $scope.pages = response.data;
    alert("....");
    clearFields();
}
```

Comment: I updated the screen shot. I was doing different attempts, I also tried response.data === undefined, but did not go the right path.

Comment: I updated with another issue I found, hopefully I'm understanding your intentions.

Comment: i added curly brackets to the if check and it is giving the same result. Please look at the updated screen shot.

Comment: Ok the next thing you need to do is copy and paste the code into your question instead of showing us a screenshot, because it needs major edits and nobody wants to (or should) retype that entire thing lol.